# Do something when offset of div is smaler than fixed value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fade the opacity of menu if it's offset to top of the window is smaler than 700px.
But I don't understand why this code doesn't work.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {      
   var offset = $(".navigation-top").offset();
   var posY = offset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
   if ($(posY) < 700) {
      $('.navigation-top').animate({'opacity':'0.1'},500);
      } else {
      $('.navigation-top').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
      }      
 });
```

Comment: Try with `if (posY < 700) {`, there is no reason to convert it into a jQuery object.

Comment: `posY` is a number. Why convert it to a jQuery object? Just write `if (posY < 700)`.

Comment: Thank you! OK - I did as you proposed, it works with extreme delay. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Thnaks to Carsten and Jeremy,

I ended up with this. But the .stop() is mantadory. Otherwise it works only with a extreme delay because of the mess of data from scrolling.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {      
   var offset = $(".navigation-top").offset();
   var posY = offset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
   if (posY < 700) {
      $('.navigation-top').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.1'},500);
      } else {
      $('.navigation-top').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
      }      
 });
```